# No popup with OpenLayers on GetFeatureInfo to MapServer WMS

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

When I click on an object on the screen I get this reply from the server:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?LAYERS=testpoint&QUERY_LAYERS=testpoint&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=517948%2C157505%2C535448%2C170005&FEATURE_COUNT=1&HEIGHT=500&WIDTH=700&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A27700&X=357&Y=241&MAP=%2FWorkTemp%2Ftest.map
```

Following this link returns the value for the object I just picked. I get no errors in the MapServer or OpenLayers log file.

OpenLayers code:

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "WMS data","http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?", {layers: 'testpoint' , map: '/WorkTemp/test.map', transparent: true},{isBaseLayer: false, opacity: 1, singleTile: true, visibility: true});
    
osMap.addLayer(layer);
    
info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
       url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?',
       title: 'Identify features by clicking',
       queryVisible: true,
       maxFeatures: 1,
       vendorParams: {
            map: '/WorkTemp/test.map'
       } ,
       info_format: 'text/html',
       layers: [layer],
       eventListeners: {
       getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
             if(event.features.length > 0) {
                     osMap.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                     "chicken", 
                     osMap.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                     null,
                     event.text,
                     null,
                     true
                     ));
             }
       }
       }
});
              
osMap.addControl(info);
info.activate();
```

test.map layer

```
LAYER
  NAME "testpoint"
  TYPE POINT
  STATUS ON
  CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
  CONNECTION "MYSQL:test,host=localhost,user=root,password=xxxxxx,port=3306"
  DATA "SELECT SHAPE,test from testpoint"
  DUMP TRUE

    TEMPLATE "c:\WorkTemp\test_template.html"

  
  LABELITEM "test"
   PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:27700"
    END
  CLASS
    NAME "test"
    STYLE
      SYMBOL  'circle'
      SIZE 10
      COLOR 255 215 0
    END
    LABEL
     COLOR  0 0 0
     FONT arial
     TYPE truetype
     SIZE 8
     POSITION AUTO
     PARTIALS FALSE
     OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
    END
  END
END # layer
```

This appears to be the same problem that I'm having:- [Use OpenLayers WMSGetFeatureInfo on Mapserver Layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21189/use-openlayers-wmsgetfeatureinfo-on-mapserver-layer), but I have already set my WMS layer to be `OpenLayers.Layer.WMS`

I downloaded and installed OSGEO4W as my starting point. I'm calling http://openspace.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/osmapapi/openspace.js for my OpenLayers commands.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come back to this project and I've managed to solve my problem.

It is all down to the response from the WMS request (text/html). This Value was never created "event.features.length". I changed it to checking that event.text had a string length greater than 0. I'm now getting popups appearing.